# echo a loop with variables command

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo

I have several lists and want to run some commands over them. As lists are long I want to run those commands parallel to each other, hence using `nohup`.
For every item I tried to `echo` a loop that contains a nohup command, but it doesn't work - `cat another_list_of_names` reads to stdout, but not into `./tools`. First `cat` in `for a in $(cat list_of_names)` sends list to loop, but `echo`'ed `for b in $(cat another_list_of_names)` sends it to stdout.
How can I set those nohup commands running in parallel (is it possible to run `nohup` with `echo`)?

```
for a in $(cat list_of_names)
      do              
          ID=`echo $a`
          mkdir ${ID}
          echo " 
             nohup sh -c '
             for b in $(cat another_list_of_names)
               do 
                  ./tools $b $a >> ${ID}/output
               done' &
           "

      done
```

Comment: `${ID}` is a directory and you are sending `stdout` to that.  Don't you need to send it to a file?  Also, in the third line, you can simply say `ID=$a`.  Or better still, use `ID` in loop header.

Comment: What is "it doesn't work" supposed to mean?

Comment: It doesn't work as `cat another_list_of_names` reads list into stdout, but not into `./tools`.

Comment: I think you have problems too due to how you're quoting variables. Things aren't going to get expanded correctly with the single quotes.

Comment: @slm I'm not quite sure what the OP intends to do, but I guess that the problems are due to the _double_ quotes. The single quoted variables should not be expanded, but since the single quotes themselves are double quoted, that fails.

Comment: @Uwe - agreed, I was just mentioning it to him. This script is extremely confusing and seems like it's doing things for no purpose.

Comment: Seems to me that the second `echo` is unnecessary.  Why can't you just do `nohup` without `echo`?

Comment: That's the question. Does he want to execute something (-> just use nohup) or does he want to see what would be executed? In the latter case, some combination involving echo makes sense, but it's still unclear how much should be expanded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what `echo` does. You cannot run *any* commands using `echo`, not specifically `nohup`. `echo` simply displays text, it does not execute it.

Now, if I understand what you want to do correctly, all you need is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
## As others have said, this is a better loop for your purposes
## and it avoids both useless uses of cat.
while read a
do         
    ## you don't need to copy the variable; you need the
    ## quotes to cope with names with spaces.    
    mkdir "$a"
    while read b
    do
      nohup ./tools $b $a >> "$a"/output &
    done < another_list_of_names
done < list_of_names
```

Comment: Will this run $b one by one or all at the same time? Because what I tried to do is to run all $b at the same time, that's why I tried using `nohup`.

Comment: @Poe they will run in parallel, that's what the `&` (run in background) at the end of the `nohup` does.

Answer (score 5):

I made some improvements to your code:

```
# This sort of loop is generally preferable to the one you had.
# This will handle spaces correctly.
while read a
do
   # There's no need for the extra 'echo'
   ID="$a"
   # Quote variables that may contain spaces
   mkdir "$ID"
   # This is a matter of taste, but I generally find heredocs to be more
   #  readable than long echo commands
   cat <<EOF
   nohup sh -c '
   while read b
   do
      # Quotation marks
      ./tools \$b $a >> "${ID}/output"
   done < another_list_of_names' &
EOF
done < list_of_names
```

Comment: This looks like a reasonable answer.  Something along the lines I had thought about as well.  I still say the question is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that I understand what you want. Just guessing: does one of the following code fragments do the intended thing?

```
for a in $(cat list_of_names)
do
    ID=`echo $a`
    mkdir ${ID}
    echo '
        nohup sh -c '\''
        for b in $(cat another_list_of_names)
        do
            ./tools $b $a >> ${ID}/output
        done'\'' &
    '
done
```

or

```
for a in $(cat list_of_names)
do
    ID=`echo $a`
    mkdir ${ID}
    echo "
        nohup sh -c '
        for b in $(cat another_list_of_names)
        do
            ./tools \$b $a >> ${ID}/output
        done' &
    "
done
```

Comment: The first code fragment won't substitute the variables `ID` and `a` within the `nohup` command.

Comment: That is because of the use of single quotes.  Single quotes prevent the variables from being substituted.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman Sure. The two fragments do different things; I just didn't know which of them the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to echo this out to see the what the final commands going to look like? or are you trying to actually trying to run the `nohup` command with that echo?

I'd suggest adding the line to the top of your script, `set -x` so that you can see what each line is doing rather than try and grok it by just looking at it.

You can turn `set -x` on off as needed in scripts too:

```
set -x

... code to debug ...

set +x
```

Comment: I edited my question with the problem I have.